# Eigen templated function that accepts both Matrix col and vector

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I can't understand how to write templated function that accepts both vector and matrix column?

For example:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void foo(
    const Eigen::MatrixX<T>& M){

}

int main(){
  Eigen::VectorX<double> v(3);
  Eigen::MatrixX<double> m(4,3);

  foo(m); // fine
  foo(m.col(0)); // broken
  foo(m.row(0)); // broken
  foo(v); // broken
}
```

only `foo(m);` is ok.

I've [seen examples](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1Ref.html) that do this with predefined types and I've seen [examples](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html) that explore templates. Neither of them do shows how to solve described task with templated function.

**Edit:**
Also I would like to pass dynamic size vector and, but not necessary, fixed size

Comment: Use `foo(m.block<4,1>(0,0));` and `foo(m.block<1,3>(0,0));` for the first two broken line.

Comment: @wcochran dosn't work... "No matching function for call 'foo'". Also I would like to pass dynamic-size vectors, because of fixed-size block limits (edited question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could get this to work using [`MatrixBase`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html):

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

template<typename T>
void foo(const Eigen::MatrixBase<T>& M){}

int main(){
    Eigen::Vector3d v(3);
    Eigen::Matrix<double,4,3> m(4,3);
    Eigen::Matrix<double,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::Dynamic> q(5,6);

    foo(m);
    foo(m.col(0));
    foo(m.row(0));
    foo(v);
    foo(q);
}
```